# Как обратиться к переменной типа QColor из другого класса?

Tags: c++, qt

У меня есть класс `chart.h` + `chart.cpp` в котором я рисую график. Там есть две переменные типа `QColor`, значения которых мне нужно изменить в слоте. Слот я реализовываю в файле `mainwindow.cpp`.

Как обратиться в этом слоте к моим двум `QColor`?

В файле chart.h

```
public:
    QColor PathColor;
    QColor LineColor;
```

В файле chart.cpp

```
void Chart:: paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget)
{
    Q_UNUSED(option); Q_UNUSED(widget);
    painter->save();

    //меняем точку начала координат
    painter->translate(m_space, (int)(boundingRect().height()/m_space-1)*m_space);

    //ширина и цвет линии графика
    painter->setPen(QPen(QColor(LineColor), 0.7));
    //размечаем точки для графика
    QPainterPath path(QPointF(0.0, 0.0));
    for(qreal x = 0.0 ; x < 15 ; x+=0.05) {
        path.lineTo(scaleX(x), scaleY(f_x(x))  );
    }

    //полупрозрачная закраска графика
    painter->setBrush(QBrush(QColor(PathColor)));
    painter->drawPath(path);
    painter->restore();
}
```

В файле maiwindow.h

```
    QGraphicsView *MainView;
    QGraphicsScene * scene; 
private slots:
    void ChengeColors();
```

Реализация слота ChengeColors

```
void MainWindow::ChengeColors()
{
    Chart.PathColor = QColor(0,0,255,200);
    Chart.LineColor = QColor(255,0,0,0);
    scene->update();
```

Мне нужно обратиться к этим двум цветам, которые определены в классе `Chart`, из файла `mainwindow.cpp` и присвоить им новые значения, но так выдает ошибки, как это сделать правильно?

Так тоже не работает Пишет returned 1 exit status

```
void MainWindow::ChengeColors()
{
    extern QColor PathColor;
    PathColor = QColor(0,0,255,200);
    extern QColor LineColor;
    LineColor = QColor(255,0,0,0);
    scene->update();
```

Comment: _«но так выдает ошибки»_ — это просто отличное описание проблемы, что из этого мы должны понять? P.S. Слово пишется «change», а не «chenge»

Comment: если я правильно понял, вам надо просто определить cеттеры (и/или uеттеры) для цветов в вашем классе `Chart` и потом обращаться к ним из класса `MainWindow`

Comment: В `MainWindow` у вас экземпляр класса `Chart` есть?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В `Chart` добавьте сеттеры:

```
void Chart::setPathColor(const QColor& color) {
    PathColor = color;
}

void Chart::setLineColor(const QColor& color) {
    LineColor = color;
}
```

`Chart` объявите членом `MainWindow` (пусть будет `m_pChart`), и в слоте уже их вызывайте для изменения цвета:

```
void MainWindow::ChengeColors()
{
    m_pChart.setPathColor(QColor(0,0,255,200));
    m_pChart.setLineColor(QColor(255,0,0,0));
    scene->update();
}
```